# Legal implications of unproven magical powers

Tags: magic, law

In this world, roughly 1% of people have actual supernatural ability (a combination of magical, deific, witchcraft, whatever). Their abilities range from the spectacular (pyromancy, flying, indestructibility) down to the quiet utility (bird poop repulsion) and all the way down to the underwhelming (a sixth sense that warns you of approaching cockroaches).

But fully 5% of people *believe* that they have magical abilities. They talk to plants, come back the next week, and they believe that the ones they spoke to are healthier than the others, ergo they MUST have a magical green thumb. Etcetera.

With that background, here's the scenario. Fred and Joe are alone together, no witnesses. They argue, and Fred pokes Joe in the chest and utters a curse. Joe immediately collapses. By the time medical help arrives, Joe is dead. An autopsy declares that Joe died of a perfectly natural heart attack. Should Fred be guilty of anything? Is there any way to ascertain whether Fred's curse was meaningful, short of having him attempt to curse someone else and seeing if they die?

Does it make a difference if Joe was known to have believed that Fred's curses have real meaning?

Comment: This depends on the specifics of country, state, and local laws, as well as existing legal precedence. Without knowing the specific jurisdiction this question is far too broad to be answerable. You can basically have it play out however you want.

Comment: @sphennings is right - note that this is not a fictitious example https://www.abc.net.au/news/2021-06-26/coronavirus-a-time-bomb-in-png-amid-sorcery-allegations/100227350

Comment: I quite like the question because it throws-up interesting possibilities, but it seems too story-based at present. Is Fred's wish-fulfillment reproducible in an ethical way for the court? (Lab mice eg.). I think you'd need to fill things out a great deal more about your [legal system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_national_legal_systems), etc.

Comment: Assume any reasonable legal basis. I have the freedom to create whatever specific laws I like, but assume that the laws will be reasonably similar to most modern Western jurisdictions. BTW, I was not aware of that page, and this isn't something that I cribbed from reality - but that's proof that we can't invent anything that hasn't already happened somewhere (the Dilbert Principle).

Comment: "Any reasonable legal basis" is way too broad. Please narrow it down.

Comment: Cursing a mouse doesn't seem very comparable, and I mention the obvious problem with having him curse another human. It's not very ethical for a legal system to risk a second murder just to find out if someone's guilty!

Comment: @ARogueAnt. Assume moral law that you, personally, would not consider overly harsh. I'm trying to design the actual laws to be such that people would generally go "yeah that's reasonable" rather than "this place has dystopian laws".

Comment: But we have members here from every country on every continent. It's not just up to me personally. Please do some research and narrow it down.

Comment: Okay, I'll narrow it down: YOU answer based on what YOU would find reasonable. I think it won't be all that different from what other people would find reasonable :)

Comment: It's my bedtime, I'll be back tomorrow however.

Comment: VTC:Needs Details. I apologize, but "YOU answer based on what YOU would find reasonable" is the basis for closing a question for needing details. Stack Exchange expects questions to be objective and detailed, leading to a single best answer. SE is not a discussion forum. You're expected to provide the framework for objectively answering a question about ***your*** world.

Comment: Plus, I object to being asked to (or compelled to) air my personal views, I'm quite happy to do so, but only as long as it is most definitely my choice, not because I'm being held to ransom by a telepath or a prognosticator, or whatever abilities exist in your world. (I guess that might be the basis of an answer!)

Comment: You ask 3 different questions. Only the second one (is it possible to ascertain whether Fred's curse was meaningful) is somewhat answerable with the information provided. You should consider editing your query to add details and limit it to 1 question (as required by the WB.SE rules).

Answer (score 3):

The only real solution to these threats I see is time. Out of 100% of the population only 6% will have any idea to even investigate. Then less the 1% could event be able to determine anything. But, now everything is recorded and this 6% can communicate with other.

Plus, A lot of it will come down to who gets the power from a grizzled police chief who can talk to the ghostly victims to a mentally unstable teen who can and does rip people limb from limb.

I reminds me of an anime, From the New World. I won't go into details, but you definitely want to be on the side with power. Because the murder, if it was one, doesn't matter. What matters is the New World and what those people with power do with it.

Comment: Another series, called Area D (only available as a manga though), shows another great solution at first: when in doubt of whom has a special ability that can be harmful and who hasn't, solve the problem by treating them all like freaks and locking them all up in an inescapable prison in a secret island (because locking away the percentage that includes people like the dude that can end your life by looking at you from a Mile away is totally a good idea with no chance of backfiring).